# VAR model with time series of different frequencies

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, unevenly-spaced-time-series

In case I want to see the effect of two or more endogenous time series on each other, I use a VAR model. But how do I proceed if one data set is monthly, and the other one daily?

Comment: The keyword for this is *mixed frequency time series*. There is a state space time series literature on this following the work of [Harvey and Pierse (1984)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2288346), and many recent contributions on mixed frequency vector autoregression models, a recent comparison of the two approaches is in [Bai, Ghysels and Wright (2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/07474938.2012.690675).

Comment: Ok thx a lot. I am studying the book of Enders, Applied econometric time series, strange that these techniques are not included.

Comment: With all due respect to Enders, these topics would be out of its scope. These topics are typically covered in graduate courses in time series (if you are lucky).

Comment: Well that is what I am having, a graduate course in time series, and hence the book "Applied econometric time series". It seems lots of topics remain uncovered after the course.

Comment: I would not call Enders a graduate textbook. To be fair, I am not sure these topics are covered in any textbook. Harvey's 1989 monograph on Kalman Filters should cover the state space part.

Comment: Useful comments by @fgnu. I've only come across only one textbook, namely, _Econometric Modelling with Time Series: Specification, Estimation and Testing_ by Martin, Hurn and Harris, that mentions mixed frequency or MIDAS models. Although not covered in detail in the book, there is an exercise question on mixed frequency models at the end of one of the chapters. It's a programming question, too. Sample code is given for R, Matlab, and Gauss. By the way, the developer of the midasr package (mpiktas) should be able to offer some good advice.